# Take Photos from camera and library

Tags: uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

hi in my app i am able to take a photo or select a photo from library and display it in a imageview

but my question is how can i add a second image view and display a image in that

here is my code

```
- (IBAction)TakePhoto:(id)sender {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)ChoosePhoto:(id)sender {    
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [ImageView setImage:image];    // "myImageView" name of any UImageView.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear? what is problem in taking second. Do same thing for second imageview imageview what u have done for first.

Comment: how would i make it display in a second imageview?

Comment: [ImageView2 setImage:image]; what else?

Comment: i want the first and second image to be different

Answer (score 0):

What I think from your question is you are going to select two image one bye one.

Either from camera or from photo library.

Try this one:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    if(ImageView.image == Nil)
    {
        [ImageView setImage:image];
    }
    else if(ImageView2.image == Nil)
    {
        [ImageView2 setImage:image];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```